# Three greatest values in an array

Tags: java, arrays

To find the three greatest elements in an array(length 100), is a combination of a for loop and an if statement(s) the most effective way, or is there a more efficient method?

Comment: I think you mean, "a combination of a for loop with if statements"

Answer (score 7):

Your question is not very clear to me.

The most efficient way would be to maintain a max heap of size `3` and insert the array elements into the max heap one by one.

At the end the `3` elements in your max heap are the `3` largest elements in the original array.

In general the problem of finding max `M` elements in an array of size `N` is best solved by maintaining a max heap of size `M`.

Answer (score 4):

For an array of length 100, and a max-3 items, you can even sort the array first and then take the top three elements - the performance difference is negligible.

For an array of greater size, a for-loop with an if comparing the 3 elements to the current one sounds fine.

If you have to find the top N elements of an M-sized array, then I think sorting would be most efficient.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could do it with a single loop through the array, and I don't think you could do it faster.  Something like:

```
int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int max3 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  //assuming integer elements in the array

for (int i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++)
{
    if (theArray[i] > max1)
    {
        max3 = max2; max2 = max1; max1 = theArray[i];
    }
    else if (theArray[i] > max2)
    {
        max3 = max2; max2 = theArray[i];
    }
    else if (theArray[i] > max3)
    {
        max3 = theArray[i];
    }
}
```

If you want the top N elements in the array, you probably just want to sort it.

Comment: What if all my array elements are negative ?

Comment: Right, or what if they're all floats, or if the array is called myArray instead of theArray?  I did improve the initial values, though.

Comment: Argh! How about Integer.MIN_VALUE?

Answer (score 2):

As this is java, you can always use a SortedSet (TreeSet for instance), that performs the sorting when elements are inserted, at a minimal cost (log(n)), and when you're done inserting, you can use descendingIterator() to retrieve the three greatest elements.

Answer (score 1):

Building onto Riley logic which skipped consideration for duplicated elements in the top 3 position here is what I propose to rectify that problem:

```
int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int max3 = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // assuming integer elements in the array

for (int i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
    if (theArray[i] > max1) {
        max3 = max2;
        max2 = max1;
        max1 = theArray[i];
    } else if (theArray[i] > max2) {
        if (max1 == theArray[i]) {
            // Neglect as already present in max1
        } else {
            max3 = max2;
            max2 = theArray[i];
        }
    } else if (theArray[i] > max3) {
        if (max1 == theArray[i] || max2 == theArray[i]) {
            // Neglect as already present in max1 OR max2
        } else {
            max3 = theArray[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is not sorted, you have to go through each element with a for loop (or something equivalent.)

There really isn't a more efficient way but to iterate for each element.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have to traverse the list once, but yes, you will have to traverse it.(assuming it is not sorted).

Answer (score 0):

The best and most efficient way (in my own opinion) would be sorting the array first (preferably with `Merge Sort`) then get the top 3 values.

Answer (score 0):

A few people are posting saying that sorting is the way to go and then grab the top 3.  However if there is a O(log N) insert into a sorted collection your will have to do it N times or to do a O(NlogN) sort (which by the way is a N^2 worst case scenario) you end up with NlogN efficiency as opposed to a simple O(N) of iterating through the array with a max1/max2/max3 like Riley posted above.  Sorting or inserting into a sorted collection is the *easiest* but not the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[10] = {-10,50,200,30,45,70,780,850,10,900};
    int i=0;
    int Max[3]={0};
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(Max[2]<a[i])
            Max[2] = a[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(Max[1]<a[i] && a[i]<Max[2])
            Max[1] = a[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(Max[0]<a[i] && a[i]<Max[1])
            Max[0] = a[i];
    }
    printf("%d %d %d",Max[2],Max[1],Max[0]);
    return 0;
}
```